# Conditional Formulas in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, formulas

I have a spreadsheet that is calculating sale rep commissions for 12 months.

On my Spreadsheet, I have a cell (`H32`) that when I enter a 1, then it calculates their Year To Date Attainment and/or Year To Date Quota, based on that number of months. That way the YTD is correct, up through that month. 
So, cell `C4` would be for July (or period 1 of that fiscal year). At the end (cell `P4`) totals the Sum of each cell (`C4`, `D4`, `E4`, etc), through all 12 months and that formula is:    `=SUM(C4:N4)`
I currently have to manually add in the month at the end of each period.

For example:

If I need to calculate July, August and September, when August closes out the formula is `=SUM(C4:D4)`, but in order to get September in there at the end of that month, in order to show the YTD total, I have to physically change that formula to `=SUM(C4:E4)`.

What I would like to do is create a Conditional If/Then statement or formula that will automatically calculate in the next cell in the chain (`D4`, `E4`, `F4`, etc), based on the number that I place in the aforementioned cell `H32`.

For Example:

If there is a 4 in `H32`, then the cell `P4` would automatically update to: `=SUM(C4:F4)`.
If I change cell `H32` to a 7, then the cell `P4` would automatically update to:  `=SUM(C4:I4)`

Comment: SUM(OFFSET(C4,0,0,H32,1))

Comment: Hey Tim, I tried this: =SUM(OFFSET(C4,0,0,N4,1)) and it didn't work. I choose N4 because in the examples above N4 is my 12th month

Comment: As Charles pointed out (thanks Charles!) you should swap the order of the last two arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a prime candidate for the INDIRECT function.

From http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx

> Use INDIRECT when you want to change the reference to a cell within a formula without changing the formula itself.

Your example would be something like

```
=SUM(C4:INDIRECT("R4C"&$H$32+2, FALSE))
```

Note that I'm using the R1C1 notation.  If H32 is `7`, then the `INDIRECT` formula will evaluate to `R4C7`, a.k.a., `G4`.  Then we add 2 to the column to make it `I7`.

Hope that makes sense, please comment if you want further clarification.

Comment: I like Tim's answer, too.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will check out this link and play with that formula this afternoon! I may come back for further questioning, but thanks so much in advance for now!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't comment on the main post or suggest an edit to Tim's comment, but he made a tiny error.  It should actually be `=SUM(OFFSET(C4,0,0,1,H32))` (switched the H32 and the last 1).  Easy mistake to make.

Comment: Hey Charles... You're AWESOME!!!!! This was exactly it and I no longer have this impending sense of doom and gllom from defeat!  LOL   Thank you BEYOND what words can express!!!

Comment: Hurrah!  No problem, Stack Overflow usually has the answers to my issues.  Just don't forget to mark my answer as the answer to your question ;)